# evitar un evento del tag <a> pero que los otros eventos funcionen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

se que se puede detener el evento de un tag `<a>` con `e.preventDefault()`

quiero saber si es posible detener solo un tipo de evento, por ejemplo:

`<a href="/home" />` quiero detener este

`<a href="#home" />` pero quiero que este funcione como es debido

hay alguna forma de hacerlo con javascript o reactjs?

Comment: puedes ponerle un id al `a` y con eso solo ponerle un `event` a ese `<a>`

Comment: @BetaM eso es lo que se me ocurrió casi al publicar la pregunta, lo hice y si funcionó

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [evitar que una etiqueta <a href="#"> reescriba la url](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358980/evitar-que-una-etiqueta-a-href-reescriba-la-url)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ponerle un Class a los enlaces que no quieres que hagan la acción y luego con un addEventListener sobre esos elementos hacer tu event.preventDefault();