# evitar que una etiqueta <a href="#"> reescriba la url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy tratando de evitar que una etiqueta `<a href="#home">` escriba la url

al darle click me pone la url `/home/#home` y quiero evitar que me ponga el `#home` pero quiero que funcione el href como es debido ya que es para dirigirte a la posición del div

e tratado de usar el `history.pushState(null, '', '/home/');` pero me sigue poniendo el `#home`

hay alguna forma de hacerlo o alguna alternativa para no usar el `<a href="#home">` y que me dirija al div y que no reescriba la url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo estás tratando de usar las anclas de `HTML` pero buscas evitar que en tu URL se vea el ID del elemento al que quieres llegar, ¿cierto?.

Si es así, se me ocurre que puedes hacerlo con `JavaScript` para poder navegar al elemento deseado sin necesidad de mostrar `#home`.

### **scrollIntoView**

El método `scrollIntoView ()` desplaza el elemento especificado al área visible de la ventana del navegador. Por Ejemplo:

```
document.getElementById("elementoID").scrollIntoView();
```

Este código deberás ponerlo en un método que se ejecute cada que des click en un link (`<a>` `</a>`) o en un botón (`<button>` `</button>`) ya sea con `jQuery` o mediante un eventListener de `JS` puro que hará el desplazamiento hasta llegar al elemento que tenga dicho ID cada que detecte la acción de click en dichas etiquetas.